# Difference between div[id=testing] and div[id$=testing] in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

**HTML**

```
<div id="testing">MY TEDT</div>
<div id="testing1">MY TEDT Number 1</div>
<div id="testing2">MY TEDT Number 2</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('div[id=testing1]').css("display", "none");
```

I have used the above jquery code for hiding the div with id testing. It is working fine. Look at the following code.

```
$('div[id$=testing1]').css("display", "none");
```

This code also doing the same. I just want to know what is the purpose of `$` using here? Because without `$` also it is working fine.

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CJe6C/)

Comment: know the difference here:: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: These things are called CSS selectors. They've been documented pretty thoroughly, both [in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) and [on the jQuery website](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) (since jQuery uses CSS selectors plus  a bit of added stuff).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one select the elements with id `testing1`. It will always select only one element. It will be better to use,`$('#testing1').css("display", "none");` since the id is unique.

Second code will select the elements with id, `ending` with `testing1`. This may select multiple elements.

Example. Second code will selects an element with id `testtesting1`. Because it has `testing1` in the end.

Comment: I know IDs must be unique. but `$('#testing1')` !== `$('div[id=testing1]')`, Second one is Attribute Equals Selector. A sample Fiddle for difference http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/HLypn/

Comment: I wouldn't even entertain the idea of multiple IDs on a page.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
$('div[id$=testing1]').css("display", "none");
```

`$` says the id which ends with testing1 apply the css to it with `display:none;`.

In the regular expression you often see these characters:

```
^ : starts with
$ : ends with
```

so if you have an element with id  some thing like this:

```
<div id="div-box">New Division</div>
```

these three are similar:

```
$('#div-box')
$('[id^="div"]')
$('[id$="box"]')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div[id=testing1]').css("display", "none");
```

is Selects all elements whose id value is testing1

and

```
$('div[id$=testing1]').css("display", "none");
```

is matches every element whose id value ends with a testing1

Answer (score 1):

`$` is **ends with**.

I recommend to use `$('#testing1')` instead of `$('div[id=testing1]')`. (first selector is much faster)

Answer (score 1):

`$` is an **ends with** selector.

So you are correct that it has no use in your example, but here:

```
$('div[id$=ting1]').css("display", "none");
```

The `id="testing1"` is still hidden.

If you want to select elements by ID you should use: `$('#testing1')` as this form of ID selector is much faster.

Documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/).